# SQL Left Outer Join 2 Tables with 2 columns and different conditions for each column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table "DT" and a mapping table "MT" as follows:

DT table:

```
ComID - CountryCode
-------------------
1000    US
1001    US
1111    FR
1222    CN
1234    CN
1333    CN
```

MT table:

```
CountryCode - Region Name - ComID
----------------------------------
   US        North America   
   US            America    1001
   FR            Europe
   CN            CHINA      
   CN            ASIA       1222 
   CN            ASEAN      1333
```

I have a view which contains those 2 tables alongside with other mapping tables as well (**Data Table** LEFT OUTER JOIN with other **Mapping Tables**)

What I want is to link the two table based on the country code, and for some exceptional companies I would like to use the ComID.

I have tried few queries but every one of them seems to not deliver the solution.
Here is my try of achieving this:

```
    Select DT.*, MT.., ...    
    FROM   DT LEFT OUTER JOIN
           MT ON DT.CountryCode = MT.CountryCode AND DT .CC_COMPANY_CODE NOT IN ('1001', '1222', '1333') OR
    DT.ComID = MTComID AND DT.ComID IN ('1001', '1222', '1333')
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ... other tables ... LEFT OUTER JOIN ... other tables ...
```

The previous will return rows where both conditions applies:

> CN -- CHINA -- 1234
>     CN -- ASIA  -- 1222
>     CN -- ASEAN -- 1333

I have tried something like this but it will return a syntax error, the solution should be around this but I couldn't seem to find it.

```
Select DT.*, MT.., ...    
        FROM   DT LEFT OUTER JOIN
               MT ON DT.CountryCode = MT.CountryCode WHERE (DT .CC_COMPANY_CODE NOT IN ('1001', '1222', '1333')) OR
        ON DT.ComID = MTComID WHERE (DT.ComID IN ('1001', '1222', '1333'))
        LEFT OUTER JOIN ... other tables ...
```

Comment: because `WHERE` clause need to be putting after all the `JOIN`, that's why you have syntax error. Secondly, you have two `ON` for your first `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: I don't understand your problem? You say you want a conditional join on `ComID` and according to your sample output this is what you are getting.

Comment: @Jacky Thanks for your input. I have multiple `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s in my view, and I need to apply specific condition for some of them.
I am aware of the 2nd `ON` in my 2nd query, each `JOIN` only accepts 1 `ON` but it was for easier understanding of what I am trying to achieve here.

Comment: @Alex My problem is that if a company code is for example **1333** then the _Region Name_ for that row should be **ASEAN** and not any other region names.
Using my query, I am getting repeated results of the same CompID with all the Region Names

Comment: you can try with your first code:  `on (DT.CountryCode = MT.CountryCode AND DT .CC_COMPANY_CODE NOT IN ('1001', '1222', '1333')) OR
   ( DT.ComID = MTComID AND DT.ComID IN ('1001', '1222', '1333'))`  take note the bracket `()` to seperate `OR`

Comment: @AliLutfi, you need to provide a complete sample output then. Then one you provided looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way to do it.

```
SELECT DT.CompID,DT.CountryCode,MT.RegionName
    FROM DT 
    JOIN MT 
        ON MT.CompID IS NOT NULL AND MT.CompID = DT.CompID
UNION
SELECT DT.CompID,DT.CountryCode,MT.RegionName
    FROM DT 
    JOIN MT 
        ON MT.CompID IS NULL AND MT.CountryCode = DT.CountryCode
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM MT WHERE CompID = DT.CompID)
```

[SQLFidder](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/764f3/1)

Try not to hard-code the CompID as part of your logic as it will not be future proof.

Comment: Thank you for the solution Docker. It has pushed more than one step into the right direction : )